# Spring boot integration tests with local postgres database creating lots of hikari connection pool

Tags: spring-boot, integration-testing, connection-pooling, junit5, hikaricp

I have lot of integration tests `@SpringBootTests` which were running with h2 before but now I am trying to use postgres to run them locally. Since application context starts every time with each tests, it's creating new hikari connection pool with every test. This is exhausting connection limit of 100 in postgres.

Is there a way application context can share connection pool (or some other way to achieve this)instead of creating new one every time?

Note: I can't share whole application context because I use MockBean and SpyBean at lot of places.

I tried lot of things, like creating singleton hikari pool in testconfiguration, singleton datasource etc

**Solution**

Create class MyBeanPostProcessor and create `static` Datasource. Trick is to create static datasource as there will only one instance of it

```
import javax.sql.DataSource;

import com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig;
import com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource;

import org.springframework.beans.BeansException;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.config.BeanPostProcessor;

public class MyBeanPostProcessor implements BeanPostProcessor {
    private static DataSource dataSource;
    static {
        final HikariDataSource hikariDataSource = new HikariDataSource();
        HikariConfig hikariConfig = new HikariConfig();
        hikariConfig.setMaximumPoolSize(30);
        hikariConfig.copyStateTo(hikariDataSource);
        hikariDataSource.setJdbcUrl("jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/test_db");
        hikariDataSource.setUsername("testuser");
        hikariDataSource.setPassword("password");
        hikariDataSource.setDriverClassName("org.postgresql.Driver");
        dataSource = hikariDataSource;
    }

    @Override
    public Object postProcessBeforeInitialization(Object bean, String beanName)
        throws BeansException {
        if (bean instanceof DataSource) {
            return dataSource;
        }
        return bean;
    }

    @Override
    public Object postProcessAfterInitialization(Object bean, String beanName)
        throws BeansException {
        return bean;
    }

}
```

Register bean in TestConfiguration

```
@TestConfiguration
public class TestContext {

    @Bean
    public MyBeanPostProcessor myBeanPostProcessor(){
        return new MyBeanPostProcessor();
    }
}
```

**Actual Test**

```
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
@SpringBootTest
@AutoConfigureMockMvc
@ActiveProfiles("test")
@TestInstance(TestInstance.Lifecycle.PER_CLASS)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = {TestContext.class})
public class MyTest {

    @Test
    public void test() {
        
    }
}
```

You can create as many integration tests and now connection pool will be shared across all tests.
Note: Make sure to increase hikari connection pool size as per your need. Since tests might be running in parallel and it might exhaust pool if pool size is small.

Comment: Each context will have its own pool, that is by design. Using `@MockBean` and `@SpyBean` will lead that for each unique combination of those a new application context (or actually your application) will be started. You also shouldn't try to share a single datasource across applications as that will lead to nice to debug errors (sarcasm mode off). You can disable (or reduce) context caching for the Spring Test Context framework (the default is 32 IIRC), you could set it to something lower like 4.

Comment: Updated description with solution. Idea was to create static Datasource so that it can be shared across tests

Comment: You could use test containers, instead of connecting directly to PostgreSQL. With that, you can have a common DB container without worrying about connection issues.

Comment: Well it "works" but you aren't using your configuration anymore as defined in your application. Now when for some reason some of your tests use a different datasource things will get interesting.

Comment: @Sam No, actually you can't exactly because DB is started before all tests and is closed after all tests finish. So every context that is created (and cached) will open 10 connections and the 10'th will exhaust the default limit of 100 open connections to PostgreSQL.